# Why is this T-SQL query throwing an "aggregate function" error message?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions, weighted-average

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following SQL query which runs fine and gives the following output:

```
SELECT 
    [PropertyCode], [BkgLeadTime], COUNT([Bkg Lead Time]) AS 'BLT COUNT' 
FROM 
    BOOKINGLEADTIME_CTE
GROUP BY 
    [PropertyCode], [Bkg Lead Time]
```

Output:

```
PropertyCode     BkgLeadTime        BLT COUNT
----------------------------------------------
   ZIL               1                4
   ZIL               2                2
   ZIL               5                1
   ZIL               7                12
```

I need to change the above query so that I get only one row as a result. Basically, I want to compute the weighted average of the output shown above.

My new query stands as follows:

```
SELECT 
    [PropertyCode], 
    SUM([Bkg Lead Time] * COUNT([Bkg Lead  Time])) / SUM (COUNT([Bkg Lead Time])) AS 'Weighted AVG BLT'
FROM 
    BOOKINGLEADTIME_CTE
GROUP BY 
    [PropertyCode]
```

However, SSMS is throwing the following error when I run the query:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

How do I modify my query to avoid this error? I understand it has to do with the aggregation syntax I've used but I can't find out the correct way to re-write this query.

Expected output is:

```
PropertyCode    Weighted AVG BLT
   ZIL             5.10
```

Comment: what is your formula for weighted average ?

Comment: `(SUM([Bkg Lead Time]) * COUNT([Bkg Lead  Time]))/(COUNT([Bkg Lead Time]))` ?

Comment: @Squirrel Formula is as mentioned in the query: 
SUM([Bkg Lead Time]*COUNT([Bkg Lead  Time]))/(COUNT([Bkg Lead Time]))

Comment: can you explain in words ?

Comment: please also post the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel I have edited my post with the expected result. Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this will help you

```
WITH CTE_TEST
AS
(   SELECT [PropertyCode], [BkgLeadTime], COUNT([Bkg Lead Time]) AS 'BLT_COUNT' 
    FROM BOOKINGLEADTIME_CTE
    GROUP BY [PropertyCode], [Bkg Lead Time]
)
SELECT SUM([BkgLeadTime]*[BLT_COUNT]) / SUM([BLT_COUNT]) FROM CTE_TEST
```

Comment: In fact, I already have a CTE running above my query (namely BOOKINGKLEADTIME_CTE) and I can't simply add this CTE at the end of the query.

Comment: @Squirrel SSMS is underlining the syntax in red meaning there is a syntax error somewhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can do multiple CTE in a statement, also you can use first CTE inside the second CTE if its really required. cte1 as (...), cte2 as (...) select *

Comment: @AbdulRasheed Perfect! Exactly what I needed! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Squirrel Thanks for pointing me to the right direction and for all your efforts!

Comment: Thankx @user3115933,@Squirrel

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT [PropertyCode]
    ,(SUM([Bkg Lead Time]) * COUNT([Bkg Lead  Time])) / COUNT([Bkg Lead Time]) AS 'Weighted AVG BLT'
FROM BOOKINGLEADTIME_CTE
GROUP BY [PropertyCode]
```